# Some Images In Azure Blob Can't Be Accessed From Web (But Some Can)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cloudberry

We have a public Azure blob that contains over 300,000 image files.  The method we used to upload the files was via a **Cloudberry Drive** mapped drive.

After uploading all the images and spot-checking them via https://ourazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/ourblob/imagefile.jpg, we are having intermittent problems.

Some of the images load up from the web just fine.  But others come up with this error from the web browsers:

Error: Code=BlobNotFound

When an image fails with "**BlobNotFound**", I am able to browse to the CloudBerry drive & path and see the image file just fine.  So I know the file exists.

Does anyone know why some images load fine from the web, and others fail?

Comment: As you said that those are public blobs, Could you please share a working and non-working (returnin BlobNotFoun) URL so we can check ?

Comment: @J.T. Have you tested my proposed solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an URI characters problem, post and review the urls, the ones are working versus the others.

If URL characters are the problems, be careful with these and use instead the encoded value

- blank characters (spaces, tab etc)
- Special characters like theses, the bold characters are the right encoded value should use if they appear :

  - + Indicates a space (spaces cannot be used in a URL). **%2B**
  - /  Separates directories and subdirectories.   **%2F**
  - ?  Separates the actual URL and the parameters.    **%3F**
  - %  Specifies special characters.   **%25**
  - # Indicates bookmarks.    **%23**
  - &  Separator between parameters specified in the URL.  **%26**

Comment: This worked for me. And, in my case I had multiple subsequent spaces. I simplified the url path.